# Git issues with Laravel Forge

Tags: git, bitbucket, laravel-forge

I'm deploying my web app using Laravel Forge and BitBucket. Recently I was coding one part of my website, and I noticed that I made small mistake in CSS, since I couldn't use `git push` because I'm not finished with coding, I changed that CSS using FTP. So after I finished with development, I tried to `git push` but I got this error (in Laravel Forge logs):

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

After I searched internet I found out that stashing would solve the problem so I changed deploy script to this:

```
cd /home/forge/default
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash apply stash@{0}
composer install
php artisan migrate --force
```

But now I receive this error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <forge@objavi.net>) not allowed
Cannot save the current index state
From bitbucket.org:alenn/objavi
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/models/Post.php
    app/models/User.php
    app/routes.php
    app/views/home.blade.php
    app/views/layouts/partials/top.blade.php
    app/views/main.blade.php
    public/css/main.css
    public/js/script.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/views/users/readlater.blade.php
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When I have to make small fixes on the server like this, my standard procedure is that once I get the fix rolled into my code, run `git checkout -- [filename]` or `git checkout -- .` to reset either the changed file or all files (if you've been mucking around in many places).

I've never tried the `git stash` method, but your server shouldn't really be a working directory, it should just receive your code.

Also, branch early, branch often. Developing in a feature branch would have let you `git checkout master`, make and push your fix, `git checkout feature-branch`, then `git merge master` to bring your fix into your feature branch and continue coding without changing files directly on the server.